# In the 2013 version with the Fire and Ice tokens, how do I move ice if it is another color's turn?

Tags: sorry

In my game, it's yellow's turn and I draw an Ice card while one of the green pawns is using it, do one of my pawns get iced, move 1 space only without using ice or, another color of my choice gets iced?

Answer (score -1):

As per the rules:
[image]

When you draw an Ice card you must move the ice token, either to one of your opponent's valid pawns, or to the center of the board, and then move one of your pawns forward 1 space.

This occurs during your turn.